# Installing DD-WRT on Dlink dir-600m

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a DLink DIR-600m [this](http://www.dlink.ir//files/products/DIR-600M_C1_Datasheet_01(HQ)(1).pdf) one. I wanted to install DD-WRT on that, for extended functionality usage monitoring. I looked up in [this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) and saw DIR-600 with revisions A1 B1/B2 supported.

I want to know if my router is supported?

If it is supported, Is it as simple as downloading firmware and uploading it in router?

If it is not supported, I want to know what other options I have to check usage metrics(tomato doesn't support DIR-600m).

I don't want people to wake up and find out router's not working. So any good resource of how to install?

Edit 1: I checked the serial number on router it is version C1. Unfortunately DD-WRT does not support that version.

Comment: You are out of luck until some one figures out how to make it work on that revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this router has only 2mb flash so cannot run dd-wrt which prefers the minimum flash of 4mb.

Comment: anyother open source firmware which we can  install on this device (dir600m)?

Comment: openwrt may work without web interface. Here is some reading. https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-600